facebook/rag-sequence-nq model related error
retriever = RagRetriever.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-sequence-nq", index_name="exact", use_dummy_dataset=True)
-- This line show error
ImportError:
RagRetriever requires the faiss library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page of its repo: https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/master/INSTALL.md and follow the ones
that match your environment. Please note that you may need to restart your runtime after installation.
why is this error showing when I am trying to use this model?
solution for this error
